# Swagger: "consumes" at operation level - Multiple request's mime types?

Tags: swagger

There are two places where we can define request mime types:

"consumes" at root level an API specification and "consumes" at operation level:

```yaml
paths:
  /survey:
    post:
      summary: A sample survey.
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: name
          type: string
          description: A persons name.
        - in: formData
          name: fav_number
          type: number
          description: A persons favorite number.
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

It makes sense that at root level "consumes" is an array, but on operation level...?
Is there a case where operation can have more than one request mime type?

Comment: Example: consume JSON or XML.

Comment: @Helen now I see, so simple,  thanks! :)